# SQL Server on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, sql-server

I've installed an SQL Server on Ubuntu 16.04. I've never installed it before, only with Windows. I followed this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ubuntu, SQL server is set.

How can I manage SQL instances from Linux, not just use Server management Studio? Are there some additional packages that need to be installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find this article useful:
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/sql-server-on-linux

I also use myself [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) to manage MySQL and occasionally MSSQL from Linux station.

Comment: That's what I've looked for, thanks for the article. I will also take a look at HeidiSQL.

Comment: You might want to look at NoSQL databases as well.